# How to enable email cloaking for my email address that is shown in rsform?

Tags: plugin, security, emails, rsform

I have a contact us form built using the **RSForm Pro** component.
At the top of the form I have a brief intro-text, using the RSForm **freetext field**, where I have my email address for those that don't want to submit the form and just like to contact me directly.

I have my form published with a RS Form menu item.
My problem is that the email cloaking plugin doesn't affect the email address that is shown inside rsform.

How can I hide my email address from bots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are 2 options:

**1. Display the form within Joomla Article.**

The first one is to inject and publish the form **within a joomla article**, where the **cloaking plugin** will be triggered. RS Form component comes with the required plugin that allows to show a form within an article.

However this might cause further issues with how the form will deal any other email addresses from inside the form, but in this case, there are [**instructions**](https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/view-article/148-my-email-field-contains-a-script.html) in RS Joomla site to deal with this.

**2. Use PHP inside RS Form.**

The other option, is to manipulate the form's output with php, within RS Form.
This is possible with the RS Form's feature, to **run php code** that is called on **Form Display**.

**Here is how to achieve it:**
In the freetext field of the form, you can replace the email address with a **special keyword**, which you can enclose inside brackets.

> E.g. Feel free to drop us an email at {email}.

the '`{email}`' is the special keyword.

Then from the **Form Properties**, in the **PHP Scripts section**, you can add the following piece of code at the first script text-area, that manipulates the form's display.

```
  //First we use Joomla's default email cloaking feature:
  $email = JHtml::_('email.cloak', 'myemail@mydomain.com');

  //Then we replace the keyword we placed previously in the freetext, with the new value of email.
  $formLayout = str_replace('{email}',$email, $formLayout);
```

The `$formLayout` is the string that contains the layout of the form. We search for our keyword inside this string and replace it with the new "cloaked" email value `$email`.

Now the email address will be protected from spambots in the front-end.

Comment: Alternatively you might be able to use Regularlab's [email protector](https://www.regularlabs.com/extensions/emailprotector). I've not tested it with RSform, but apparently it "is a system plugin and is written in a way that it will cloak email adresses in your entire website. So also in modules and 3rd party extensions."